# Inserir chave estrangeira hibernate

Tags: jsf, hibernate

Possuo quatro entidades (selecao, partida, aposta e apostador) onde dentro da classe Aposta possuo os IDs de uma aposta e de um apostador. Quando vou tentar inserir uma aposta carregando dentro dele a partida e o apostador, me gera o seguinte erro:

> org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save():

Classe Aposta

```
public class Aposta implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "idAposta")
private Integer idAposta;
@Size(max = 3)
@Column(name = "Palpite")
private String palpite;
@Size(max = 1)
@Column(name = "Status")
private String status;
@JoinColumn(name = "Apostador_idApostador", referencedColumnName = "idApostador")
@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 
private Apostador apostadoridApostador;
@JoinColumn(name = "Partida_idPartida", referencedColumnName = "idPartida")
@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Partida partidaidPartida;
```

Acredito que seja algum mapeamento agora não sei qual. Pesquisei que precisava adicionar o parâmetro cascade dentro do @ManyToOne mas mesmo assim não rolou.

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10997869/3681565) resposta, você precisa colocar a assinatura para auto incrementar os IDs de sua `Entity`. Utilize `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)` nos campos que são `@Id` que já vai fazer isto automático.